# What do the letters on an external light bulb model mean?

Tags: lights

For example, the owners manual for my 2009 Focus says it needs 3457 NAK or 3457 AK for the park and turn lamps. What is the significance behind each letter?

Comment: Try a google search (works wonders) https://rec.autos.makers.chrysler.narkive.com/SV6MxFE8/3057na-3157na-3357nak-3457nak-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the NA represents natural amber glass color with krypton gas to increase bulb life. Ak represents amber coated bulb with krypton gas. This information is available on most major bulb suppliers tech page.